# React-native problem with repeating questions in quiz app

Tags: database, react-native

I'm a beginner to react-native and maybe my question is stupid, but I'm building a quiz app, that takes data from local database - data.js. Random questions are loading properly, but I don't want them to repeat. I just want to load question(this part is done) and after that prevent it from loading again.

I tried to check if data.length > 0  then I generate random question. After that I remove this question from data to prevent it from repeating and everything works fine but after reaching data.length = 0 it does nothing because there are no questions left.
I tried to append newData using .concat() but when I remove question from data it also removes question from newDeta. How can I fix it and load data again so that you can take quiz as long as u want?

Please help me I cannot deal with it.

Here's fragment of my code:

```
import { data } from './data.js'

const newData = require('./data.js')

    const getQuestions = () => {
        if(data.length > 0){
            setSelectedOptions({});
            setShowResult(false);

            const currentQuestion = data.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random())
            const slicedQuestion = currentQuestion.slice(0, 1)
                
            if(slicedQuestion[0].category === category){
                setQuestions(slicedQuestion) 
            }
            else{
                getQuestions();
            }
        }
        else{
            data.length = 0
            data.concat(newData.data)
        }

    }

    const handleNext = () => {
        questions.forEach((questions, index) => {
            if(selectedOptions[index] === questions.correctOption){
                const indexElement = data.indexOf(questions)
                data.splice(indexElement, 1)
                console.log(data.length)
                navigation.navigate('Correct Site');
                getQuestions();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know where I made a mistake. I fixed it by simply creating a copy of my local database to a new array and then loading questions from this copied array. After that I every time I load question I delete question from copied array.